# Is there a way to tell DWR to ignore a lazily-initialized field?

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading, dwr, lazy-initialization

I'm using DWR 3.0.0-rc2, Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE,Hibernate 4.1.0.Final.  I have this domain object …

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid-strategy", strategy = "uuid.hex")
@Entity
@Table(name = "sb_product")
@Cacheable
@DataTransferObject
public final class Product implements Serializable, Comparable<Product>
{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid-strategy")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "ISBN")
    @NotEmpty
    private String isbn;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;
    …
    @ManyToMany
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    @JoinTable(name = "sb_product_std_category", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID") },    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "STD_CATEGORY_ID") })
    private List<StandardCategory> standardCategories;
```

When I invoke DWR on a service method that returns the above object, I get the exception "Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.mainco.subco.ecom.domain.Product.standardCategories, no session or session was closed".  I don't care about the field that is lazily initialized.  Is there a way I can tell DWR to ignore that field when marshaling the data?  Below is the complete exception.  Thanks, - Dave

```
12:43:18,169 WARN  [org.directwebremoting.convert.CollectionConverter] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-4) Conversion error for java.util.ArrayList.:  org.directwebremoting.ConversionException: Error marshalling data. See the logs for more details.
    at org.directwebremoting.convert.BasicObjectConverter.convertOutbound(BasicObjectConverter.java:310) [dwr-3.0.0-rc2.jar:]
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultConverterManager.convertOutbound(DefaultConverterManager.java:441) [dwr-3.0.0-rc2.jar:]
    at org.directwebremoting.convert.CollectionConverter.convertOutbound(CollectionConverter.java:213) [dwr-3.0.0-rc2.jar:]
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultConverterManager.convertOutbound(DefaultConverterManager.java:441) [dwr-3.0.0-rc2.jar:]
    at org.directwebremoting.extend.ScriptBufferUtil.createOutput(ScriptBufferUtil.java:68) [dwr-3.0.0-rc2.jar:]
    at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.BaseCallHandler$CallScriptConduit.addScript(BaseCallHandler.java:485) [dwr-3.0.0-rc2.jar:]
    at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.BaseCallHandler.marshallOutbound(BaseCallHandler.java:345) [dwr-3.0.0-rc2.jar:]
    at org.directwebremoting.dwrp.BaseCallHandler.handle(BaseCallHandler.java:105) [dwr-3.0.0-rc2.jar:]
    at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:120) [dwr-3.0.0-rc2.jar:]
    at org.directwebremoting.spring.DwrController.handleRequestInternal(DwrController.java:234) [dwr-3.0.0-rc2.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153) [spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48) [spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923) [spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:   3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) [spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar: 3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789) [spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:   3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) [spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:    7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [classes.jar:1.6.0_41]
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.mainco.subco.ecom.domain.Product.standardCategories, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:394) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:386) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:379) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:113) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:266) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
    at org.directwebremoting.convert.CollectionConverter.convertOutbound(CollectionConverter.java:189) [dwr-3.0.0-rc2.jar:]
    at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultConverterManager.convertOutbound(DefaultConverterManager.java:441) [dwr-3.0.0-rc2.jar:]
    at org.directwebremoting.convert.BasicObjectConverter.convertOutbound(BasicObjectConverter.java:299) [dwr-3.0.0-rc2.jar:]
    ... 57 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `HibernateBeanConverter`. Check for documentation [here](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/server/integration/hibernate.html).